# How to enroll device onto android enteprise?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I have created Android enterprise then enrolled the device on using the QR code, the device does say its enrolled and managed by Organisation. But the weird part is it trying to get the list of device return empty object, and also the app which I had put on policy to be forced to install didn't install. What could be the problem in my enrollment?

Comment: Check out this https://onlinesupport.miradore.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000527865-How-to-enable-a-work-profile-on-Android-devices
 It will help you understand how to enroll the device into an Android enterprise.

Comment: Thanks @mdroid let me have a look at it